# Trying to only add unique values to my array and "inArray" is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to populate an array (rulesArray) with the labels associated with checked checkboxes. I am also trying to be sure I only add unique values (this is where the `!inArray` comes in). I'm pretty sure at this point that this is incorrect syntax for `inArray`.

Currently my error is `"Uncaught ReferenceError: inArray is not defined."`

Here is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rulesArray = [];
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
        $('input.selectBox').each(function(){
            if(($(this).is(':checked')) && (!inArray($(this).parent().text(), rulesArray))){
                rulesArray.push($(this).parent().text());
            }
        });
        console.log(rulesArray);
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div>
    <button class="toggle_button" data-contents=".item_8"></button> 
    <ul class="contents item_8"> 
        <li><input class="selectBox" type="checkbox" id="color_1" name="color_1" value=""><label for="color_1">Red</label></li>
        <li><input class="selectBox" type="checkbox" id="color_2" name="color_2" value=""><label for="color_2">Orange</label></li>
        <li><input class="selectBox" type="checkbox" id="color_3" name="color_3" value=""><label for="color_3">Yellow</label></li>
        <li><input class="selectBox" type="checkbox" id="color_4" name="color_4" value=""><label for="color_4">Green</label></li>
        <li><input class="selectBox" type="checkbox" id="color_5" name="color_5" value=""><label for="color_5">Blue</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be $.inArray- it's a jquery method?

Comment: You need to use  $.inArray. Unless you've defined your own inArray in your current scope.

Comment: There's a lot of fail here, in particular that there's no logic to _remove_ an unchecked element from the array

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have solved my error on inArray being undefined. Now its returning an empty array when I click.

Answer (score 4):

The correct method is `$.inArray` - not `inArray` - you can shorten your code tho with a better selector and using a vanilla `indexOf` call:

```
$('input.selectBox').each(function(){
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    var txt = $(this).parent().text();
    var idx = rulesArray.indexOf(txt);

    if (isChecked && idx === -1) {
        rulesArray.push(txt);
    } else if (!isChecked && idx > -1) {
        rulesArray.splice(idx, 1);
    }
});
```

And a solution using `$.map`

```
var rulesArray = $('input.selectBox:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).parent().text();
}).get();
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help. I attempted indexOf previously and obviously overcomplicated it.

Comment: personally, I'd use a `Map`

Comment: @Alnitak -- Added a solution for that as well! Thanks!

Comment: Although good - that's not quite what I meant, and you'd need to use `.get()` on the end of that to turn the resulting jQuery object into a plain array.

I meant "use an ES6 `Map`" (or abuse an `Object` as a key-value store)

Comment: Always forget about the `.get()` - and I guess I can't really picture what you're talking about - why use the native `.map` over jQuery `map` here?

Comment: Actually, in ES6 you could use `Set` instead of `Map`, the former being exactly the required data structure to maintain a set of unique entries.

Comment: I really need to look more at ES6 - slacking on that :\